# Align two columns inside a list

Tags: html, css

Every img in the list at the end of [this html page](https://www.superinformati.com/dimagrire/kayla-itsines-bgg.htm) is set to be large 50px, but they disrespect this rule. I've tried playing with display and box-sizing but I still can't get what's breaking the CSS box model.

I've copied the HTML/CSS in the widget here also.

[image]

```css
div.thumbnail-list {
  column-count: 2;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

ol.thumbnail-list,
ul.thumbnail-list {
  /*margin: 1.2em 0 1.2em 1em;*/
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

ol.thumbnail-list li,
ul.thumbnail-list li {
  /*position: relative;*/
  /*padding: .4em .4em .4em 2em;*/
  /*line-height: 0;*/
  background: #efefef;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  /*!*border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;*!*/
  /*!*display: table;*!*/
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

ol.thumbnail-list li a,
ul.thumbnail-list li a {
  display: flex; /* establish flex container */
  flex-direction: row; /* make main axis horizontal (default value) */
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center; /* center items vertically, in this case */
  /*height: 50px;*/
  /*background-color: #eee;*/
}

ol.thumbnail-list li + div,
ul.thumbnail-list li + div {
  display: flex; /* establish flex container */
  flex-direction: row; /* make main axis horizontal (default value) */
  justify-content: left; /* center items horizontally, in this case */
  align-items: center; /* center items vertically, in this case */
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

div.container li.container {
  display: flex; /* establish flex container */
  flex-direction: row; /* make main axis horizontal (default value) */
  justify-content: left; /* center items horizontally, in this case */
  align-items: center; /* center items vertically, in this case */
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.li-text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  padding-left: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.94em;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

div.li-img img,
img.li-img {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
{

  .li-text {
    line-height: normal;
    font-size: 0.54em;
  }

  img.li-img img {
    max-width: 50px;
    max-heigth: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail-list"><ul class="thumbnail-list"><li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/imagrire-pancia-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Dimagrire pancia </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/come-dimagrire-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Come dimagrire </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/menopausa-dieta-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Dimagrire in Menopausa </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/integratori-per-dimagrire-velocemente-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Integratori per dimagrire </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/dimagrireinfretta-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Dimagrire in fretta </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/dimagrire-con-la-corsa-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Dimagrire correndo </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/dieta-in-gravidanza-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Dimagrire in gravidanza </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/non-riesco-a-dimagrire-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Non riesco a dimagrire: cause </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/cyclette-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Dimagrire con la cyclette </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/come-dimagrire-i-fianchi-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Dimagrire i fianchi </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/dimagrire-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Dimagrire 5 o 10 kg </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/integratori-e-farmaci-per-dimagrire-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Farmaci per dimagrire </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/alimenti-vitamina-e-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Cibi che fanno dimagrire </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/magrire-gambe-cosce-come-fare-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Dimagrire cosce </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/dimagrire-camminando-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Dimagrire camminando </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/dimagrire-velocemente-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Dimagrire in una settimana </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/BBG-Kayla-Itsines-1-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Trucchi per dimagrire </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/BBG-Kayla-Itsines-1-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Dimagrire con Total Crunch </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/come-allenarsi-a-casa-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Allenarsi a casa </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/come-dimagrisco-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Come dimagrisco in fretta? </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/peso-forma-peso-ideale-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Calcolo peso forma e peso ideale </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/str-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Stretching </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/phaa-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Allenamento PHA </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/BBG-Kayla-Itsines-1-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Allenamento BGG ()</div>
</li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/BBG-Kayla-Itsines-1-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Esercizi anticellulite </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/spinning-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Spinning </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/pillole-dimagranti-funzionano-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Pillole dimagranti efficaci </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/home-fitness-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Home fitness </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/dieta-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Perdere 3 kg in una settimana </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/app-per-allenarsi-a-casa-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">App per allenarsi a casa </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/cellulite1-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Come eliminare la cellulite </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/flying-suspension-training-sidea-1160x800-1-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Allenamento funzionale </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Cerotti-per-dimagrire-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Cerotti dimagranti </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/come-dimagrire-braccia-senza-muscoli-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Esercizi braccia </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/esercizi-addominali-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Esercizi addominali </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/aerobica-anaerobica-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Attività aerobica e anaerobica </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/perdere-5-kg-in-un-mese-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Perdere 5 kg in un mese </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Esercizi-TRX--150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Esercizi TRX </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/yoyo-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Yoga </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/massa-magra-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Massa magra </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/come-allenarsi-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Allenarsi in maniera efficace </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/medi-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Meditazione </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/bmi-150x150.png">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Indice di Massa corporea </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/massa-grassa-150x150.jpeg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Massa grassa </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/pancia-piatta-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Sgonfiare la pancia </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/seno-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Rassodare il seno </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/tabata-training-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Allenamento Tabata </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/hiit2-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Allenamento HIIT </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/integratori-termogenici-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Integratori termogenici </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/integratori-palestra-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Integratori palestra </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/BCAA-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">BCAA </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/allenarsi-con-manubri-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Allenarsi con i manubri </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/esercizi-corpo-libero-casa-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Esercizi a corpo libero </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/allenarsi-a-casa-o-in-palestra-con-gli-elastici-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Allenarsi con gli elastici </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/allenare-i-glutei-a-casa-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Allenare i glutei </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/walking-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Camminata Veloce </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/bruciare-grassi-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Bruciare i grassi velocemente </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/perdere-peso-in-una-settimana-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Come perdere peso in una settimana </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/panca-palestra-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Panca da palestra </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/panca-addominale-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Panca addominali </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/cellulite-rimedi-naturali-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Rimedi Naturali cellulite </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/smagliature-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Smagliature </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/smagliature-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Come eliminare le smagliature </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/cellulite1-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Trattamenti contro la cellulite </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/cellulite-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Cellulite </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/allenamento-in-bici-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Allenamento Bici per dimagrire </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/ginnastica-per-dimagrire-10-kg--150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Ginnastica per dimagrire 10 kg </div>
</a></li>
<li>
<a>
<div class="li-img">
<img width="50" height="50"     src="https://www.superinformati.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/schiena-esercizi-150x150.jpg">
</div>
<div class="li-text">Esercizi per la schiena </div>
</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the CSS min-width property. Makes sure that the element is at least that size.

eg:

```
min-width: 50px;
```